# In Excel, How do I return a list of values that match a description?

Tags: excel, list, indexing

My question is that I want to return a list of values in column B in sheet 2 (or in this case NBA Players) that contain the value "PG" in cell A3 in sheet 1, from column A in sheet 2.  Not only do I want it to match "PG" but I also want the value to have a salary (Column C) that is between $7100 (Cell B2 in Sheet 1) and $8000 (Cell C2) in Sheet 1).  Any help would be appreciated.

[image: (Sheet 2) I want to get the information from]

[image: (Sheet 1) I want my list to appear]

Answer (score 0):

you are either going to need to use an array formula or a function that returns array like calculations.  I will suggest using the AGGREGATE function.  Avoid using full comm/row references within an array formula or a function performing array like calculations or you may wind up bogging down your system with excessive calculations.

The AGGREGATE function is made up a several individual functions.  Depending which one you choose, it will perform array operations.  I am going to suggest that formula 14.  What the following example will do is generate a list of results sorted from smallest to largest that ignores error values, then return the first value from the list.  The thing we will list is the row number for a row that matches your ALL your criteria.  So the basics of AGGREGATE looks like this:

```
AGGREGATE(Formula #, Error/hidden handling #, Formula, parameter)
```

The hardest part of this is coming up with the right formula.  In the numerator you put the thing you are looking for.  In the denominator you place your TRUE/FALSE condition checks.  Separate each condition check with *.  * will act as an AND function.  The thing  that makes this work is that TRUE/FALSE convert to 1/0 when they are sent through a math operation.  So anything you do not want is FALSE.  and anything divided by FALSE becomes divide by 0 which in turn generates an error.  Since AGGREGATE is set to ignore error, only things that meet your condition will exist in the list and since they are being divided by TRUE which is 1, your thing remains unchanged.  So the aggregate function is going to start to look like:

```
AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(some range)/((Condition 1)*Condition 2)*...*(Condition N)),1)
```

So as eluded to before, 14 set the AGGREGATE to sort a list in ascending order.  6 tells AGGREGATE to ignore errors, and the 1 tells AGGREGATE to return the first item in its sorted list.  If it was 2 instead of 1 it would return the 2nd position.  If you ask for a position that is greater than the number of items in the list, there will be an error produced by AGGREGATE which does not get ignored.

So now that there is some understanding of what AGGREGATE does lets see how we can apply this to your data.  For starters lets assume your data is in rows 2:100 and row 1 is a header row.  You will have to adjust the references to suit your data.

CONDITION 1

```
LEFT($A$2:$A$100,2)="PG"
```

Checks to see if the first two characters are PG.  based on the data in  your screen shot, PG was either to the left of the / or was the only entry.  There was also an observation that there was only one / in the cells of column A.  If you also need to check if it after the / and with the assumption that it can only be on one side and not both at the same time you could use this alternative for your condition check:

```
(LEFT($A$2:$A$100,2)="PG")+(RIGHT($A$2:$A$100,2)="PG")
```

In this case the + is performing the task of an OR function.  The caveat mentioned earlier is important because if both sides are TRUE then you wind up with TRUE+TRUE which becomes 1+1 which is 2 and we only want to divide by 1 or 0.  Though to counter that you could go with:

```
MIN((LEFT($A$2:$A$100,2)="PG")+(RIGHT($A$2:$A$100,2)="PG"),1)
```

CONDITION 2

Check that the salary in C is less than or equal a value 80000.

```
($C$2:$C$100<=80000)
```

CONDITION 3

Check that the salary in C is greater than or equal a value 71000.

```
($C$2:$C$100>=71000)
```

Now lets put this all together to get a list of row numbers that meet your conditions:

```
AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($A$2:$A$100)/MIN((LEFT($A$2:$A$100,2)="PG")+(RIGHT($A$2:$A$100,2)="PG"),1)*($C$2:$C$100<=80000)*($C$2:$C$100>=71000),ROW(A1))
```

Now provided I did not screw up the bracketing in that formula, you can place that formula in a cell and copy it down until it produces errors.  As you copy it down, the only thing that will change is the A1 in ROW(A1).  It acts like a counter.  1,2,3 etc.  so you will get a list of row numbers that meet your criteria.  Now we need to convert those row numbers to names.

To find the names, the INDEX function is your friend here.  Because it is not part of an array formula or inside a function performing array like calculations, full column reference can be used.  So we take our formula that is generating row numbers and place it inside the INDEX function to give:

```
INDEX(B:B,Row Number)

INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($A$2:$A$100)/MIN((LEFT($A$2:$A$100,2)="PG")+(RIGHT($A$2:$A$100,2)="PG"),1)*($C$2:$C$100<=80000)*($C$2:$C$100>=71000),ROW(A1)))
```

Now if you hate seeing error codes when you have copied down further then results you can place the whole thing inside and IFERROR function to give:

```
IFERROR(formula,What to display in case of an error)
```

So for blank entries:

```
IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($A$2:$A$100)/MIN((LEFT($A$2:$A$100,2)="PG")+(RIGHT($A$2:$A$100,2)="PG"),1)*($C$2:$C$100<=80000)*($C$2:$C$100>=71000),ROW(A1))),"")
```

and custom message:

```
IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($A$2:$A$100)/MIN((LEFT($A$2:$A$100,2)="PG")+(RIGHT($A$2:$A$100,2)="PG"),1)*($C$2:$C$100<=80000)*($C$2:$C$100>=71000),ROW(A1))),"NOT FOUND")
```

So now you just need to adjust the references to suit your data.  If your data is located on another sheet remember to include the sheet name.  A reference to B3:C4 would become:

```
Sheet1!B3:C4
```

and if the sheet name has a space in it:

```
'Space Name'!B3:C4
```